# calculate max and min number in range

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm writing a script that's supposed to selectively add hidden to div elements based on which page has been selected.
Each section should have 16 images so the sections go as follows

```
Section 1: 1 - 16
Section 2: 17 - 33
Section 3: 34 - 40
Section 4: 41 - 57
```

I'm trying to figure out an equation given the page number can derive the range start and end.
My first assumption was from 2 onwards it would be

```
Section 2: (((section_num - 1) * 16) + 1) - (section_num * 16) + 1
           (16 + 1) - (16 * 2) + 1
           17 - 33
```

But it doesn't always follow this line.

Comment: This is not linear algebra.

Comment: think it's basic algebra but that's the only near algebra that was on the tag

Comment: If you looked sown, you would see the [algebra-precalculus] tag, which is more appropriate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've taken the first "inteverval" to be $1-16$, the ending page (16 in the first case) for any section will be 16*(section number) and NOT 16*(section number). You can also see it like: Let n be current section number, and $x$ be it highest page #. Then, by what you wrote, $x=16n+1$. Also, the lowest page # in $(n+1)th$  section $=((n+1)-1)*16+1=16n+1=x$, which isn't true right?

Instead, if you take what I said, i.e, $x=16n$, then the lowest page in next section will be $=((n+1)-1)*16+1=16n+1=x+1$, which is obviously correct.

Your formula for lower page number was CORRECT anyway!